# Swagger UI 2.9.2 not showing services under controller agrupations

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, springfox

I'm using springfox swagger to document the REST web services under a Spring Boot project, but swagger-ui is not working... I get to the index page and see all the controller agrupations, but when I select any of them, no services are shown.
I have followed the instructions as explained here:
https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api

Viewing code behind the index page of the swagger-ui I see there are a lot of errors, all of them are the same:

> system.js:461 TypeError: Array.prototype.filter called on null or
>   undefined
>       at filter ()
>       at system.js:458
>       at Object.currentFilter (system.js:262)
>       at t.value (filter.jsx:24)
>       at t.render (root-injects.js:93)
>       at u._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (ReactCompositeComponent.js:796)
>       at u._renderValidatedComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:819)
>       at u.performInitialMount (ReactCompositeComponent.js:359)
>       at u.mountComponent (ReactCompositeComponent.js:255)
>       at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:43) (anonymous) @ system.js:461

I have also tried to see if the JSON received by v2/api-docs had anything extrange, but nothing... everything seems fine.

Now something even stranger... I have tried with swagger version 2.8.0, and then swagger-ui shows everything correctly. BUT! If I look at the code behind, the same errors are displayed.

Any recomendation?

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working... the problem was I set up the security of spring to access certain controllers and had added some of thee paths swagger needs at the whitelist, but had missed 2 paths swagger needed. I added them and now everything works fine... here are the paths I have added to the whitelist for swagger to work:

```
        <url path="/webjars/**" />
        <url path="/v2/**" />
        <url path="/configuration/**" />
        <url path="/swagger*/**" />
```